# MongoDB, how to convert string to array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a string value that contains an Array of Objects I want to filter that value based on specific values from that object (ex: stage===1 && state==="not-started"). The string Array is like below.

```
"sts" : "[{\"percentage\":0,\"stage\":\"Stage1\",\"timestamp\":\"2020-02-11T09:52:53.018Z\",\"state\":\"not-started\",\"information\":\"Stage1 not started yet\",\"order_no\":0,\"display-name\":\"UNKNOWN ALL\"},{\"percentage\":0,\"stage\":\"Stage2\",\"timestamp\":\"2020-02-11T09:52:53.018Z\",\"state\":\"not-started\",\"information\":\"Stage2 is not started yet\",\"order_no\":1,\"display-name\":\"Stage2\"},{\"percentage\":0,\"stage\":\"Stage3\",\"timestamp\":\"2020-02-11T09:52:53.018Z\",\"state\":\"not-started\",\"information\":\"Stage3 is not started yet\",\"order_no\":2,\"display-name\":\"Stage3\"},{\"percentage\":0,\"stage\":\"Stage4\",\"timestamp\":\"2020-02-11T09:52:53.018Z\",\"state\":\"not-started\",\"information\":\"Stage4 is not started yet\",\"order_no\":3,\"display-name\":\"Stage4\"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to array like:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(yourObject.sts);
```

where `sts` is key of the object you have shared as an example.

and then filter it like:

```
var data = arr.filter(({stage, state}) => stage==="Stage1" && state==="not-started")
```